# Does Caps Lock indicate whether an OS is installed?

Tags: operating-systems, capslock

Someone told me if the <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> works when I turn a desktop computer on, an OS is installed. Otherwise, there's no OS. Is that true?

Comment: Unplug your hard drive(s), boot the computer, and hit Caps Lock... Does it light up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> does not indicate whether an OS is installed. However, most newer motherboards show the boot partition in the BIOS, e.g. `Windows Loader on HDD1` or something similar indicating that an OS is installed.